# Upon double clicking a cell, copy cell value to another cell on that same row

Tags: vba, excel

This VBA code does what I need but only on one row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:H1")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True

    If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B"), Target.Value) = 0 Then
        Range("B1").Value = Target.Value
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

I have on my Excel worksheet:

```
A    B   C    D    E   F   G   H
MAN     NN   NNP  JJ  POS
CAN     MOD  NN   VV   JJ  RB  NON
...     ...
```

up to 300,000 data.

I want when I double click any cell in C:H range, its value will be copied to B. The above code handles one row only. If I change C1:H1 to C2:H2 and B1 to B2, it will handle the second row.

How do I make it work for all rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following change will work (not tested, on iPhone):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:H")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True

        If Application.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B"), Target.Value) = 0 Then
            Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code will exit the sub if the user double clicks on `C:H`

Comment: All that needs to be changed in the original code is `Range("B1").Value = Target.Value` with `Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value = Target.Value` and of course `Range("C1:H1")` with `Range("C:H")`

Comment: @SiddharthRout - thanks for spotting that. I assumed (looking at code on iPhone which messed up line wrapping horribly) that `Cancel = True` meant "nothing to do here". The `Exit Sub` was indeed wrong. Fixed it now.